# Looping through component the classname is only changed on the first div

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Using a button I am trying to show a new component by incrementing a state value and apply a keyword to the currently active div classname if they have the same id as the state.

```
 handleSave = () => {
    this.setState({activeItemId: this.state.activeItemId + 1}, () => {

    });
  }
```

Apply 'active' classname to the currently active component iteration.

```
<div className={`wrapper
        ${this.props.questions.qId == this.state.activeItemId ? 'active' : ''}
        `}>
```

However this change is only propagated to the first div. This means 'active' is removed from the first div but it is never appended to the second. Likewise I can not remove active from the second component if they are rendered with the same qId, 'active' is only removed from the first div.

Can you tell me why this change is only registered on the first iterated component and not the second?

**EDIT: I realized that the button is somehow bound to the each individual component, so I can only hide the div by using the button associated with that particular component. I can only presume a new state object was instantiated for each and every component while I need to access the state object of the parent component instead.**

This code worked:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {answer: 0, activeItemId: '0' };
    this.handleSave = this.handleSave.bind(this)
  }

    handleSave = () => {
    this.setState({answer: this.state.value});
    this.setState({activeItemId: this.state.activeItemId + 1}, () => {
    });
  }
```

and the mapping

```
const question = Object.values(questions.questions).map((data, index) =>
<QuestionList questions={data} key={index} handleSave={this.handleSave} activeItemId={this.state.activeItemId}/>
```

Comment: You should be using triple equals. Sorry, I know this doesn't answer your questions but worth mentioning.

Comment: Thank you! I noticed the linter complaining about this, but I was wondering if my json was returning a string while my state was storing an integer but it did not seems to matter and I will be changing to triple equals when I find a working solution :)